# Resending Commits to Github?

Tags: github, ssh

I have a dilemma... I got a new computer and set up new SSH with Github, and then push up commits. However, since my email address wasn't the same as the one on Github, these commits didn't show up or register with my profile. I didn't realize this until a week later. I changed my email and my commits are showing up now... however the previous commits I've done are still missing. Is there a way to get these to show back up?

Answer (score 1):

[You may add more than one email address to your GitHub profile](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/) which will make both your past and current commits show up under your name.

Comment: [Are you seeing a question mark icon next to the commits that are not associated with your account explaining why the commit is not linked?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/#commits-are-not-linked-to-any-user)